# Use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to update row with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've the following table structure:

Table `___Availabilities` :

```
|--------|------------|------------|------------|
| AVA_Id | AVA_RoomId | AVA_Date   | AVA_Status |
|--------|------------|------------|------------|
|      1 |         47 | 2019-03-11 |     NoData |
|      2 |         48 | 2019-03-22 |       Book |
|      3 |         48 | 2019-03-23 |       Book |
|--------|------------|------------|------------|
```

I want to UPDATE the `AVA_Status` only if `AVA_RoomId` and `AVA_Date` are know in a row of the table. If not, INSERT a new row.

So my query is this one:

```
INSERT INTO ___Availabilities 
    (AVA_Id, AVA_RoomId, AVA_Date, AVA_Status) 
    VALUES('', '103', '2019-04-04', 'Open')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `AVA_RoomId`='47',
    `AVA_Date`='2019-03-11'
```

But it doesn't work as it added a new row whereas it should update the row where `AVA_RoomId = 47` and `AVA_Date = 2019-03-11`.

Why my query is not working please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `AVA_Id` an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, yes it is.

Comment: You need a unique index on the columns that you want to match for `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Comment: Do you have a unique index on `(AVA_RoomId, AVA_Date)`?

Comment: It cannot work since key will not be duplicate.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone What are you talking about? If he has a unique key on the room and date columns, it will be a duplicate.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, so I will need to make this in two queries ?

Comment: @Barmar I think the problem is, OP wants to update the row with values ('47', '2019-03-11') **if it exists** with the values ('103', '2019-04-04', 'Open'), otherwise insert a new row with those values.

Comment: That's really weird. Usually you use this to update the dependent columns, not the key columns. But I think it should still work.

Comment: OP wants to update the row with `AVA_RoomId = 47 and AVA_Date = 2019-03-11`if it exists otherwise insert a new row.

Comment: Oh, now I see, he wants to go the other way. He wants to change a row if it exists, otherwise add a new row. `ON DUPLICATE KEY` tries to add a row, and changes the row if it already exists.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this, it will have to be two queries. And use a transaction around them.

Comment: *"update the row with AVA_RoomId = 47 and AVA_Date = 2019-03-11if it exists"* does not seem to make much sense. So as long as this combination does not exist, you want to insert a new room/date, but once this combination was inserted, you want to update that row all the time? Can you explain why?

Comment: You might want, as already suggested, a unique index on the two columns and update the field `AVA_Status` instead. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE AVA_Status='open'` You do not need to mention the ID column and the corresponding value.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, sorry, I want to update the `AVA_Status` only if `AVA_RoomId` and `AVA_Date` are know in a  row. If not, add a new row. Is is possible with my actual query?

Comment: If `AVA_Id` an auto increment column, why are you putting it in `insert` and passing blank string as a value?

Comment: Even if clarifying was a hard birth, +1 for the effort to improve your question by editing.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine the circumstances under which you'd want to do this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a `UNIQUE INDEX(AVA_RoomId, AVA_Date)`

You might want to update the `AVA_Status` when the combination of room and date already exists:

```
INSERT INTO ___Availabilities 
    (`AVA_RoomId`, `AVA_Date`, `AVA_Status`) 
    VALUES('103', '2019-04-04', 'Open')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `AVA_Status` = VALUES(`AVA_Status`),
```

As @Barmar already explained, if not already done, you can still add an index after table creation:

```
ALTER TABLE `___Availabilities`
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `uq_room_date` (`AVA_RoomId`, `AVA_Date`)
;
```

Comment: Hello, does it mean that `AVA_RoomId` and `AVA_Date ` should be unique? Because it will not be the case as I will have more than one row for the same RoomId but with several different dates.

Comment: of course or new duplicate index can be recognized.

Comment: @Testy I guess you want to update the value provided by insert instead of a constant. See the update.

Comment: It's working. How can I manage the `AVA_Id` as it's an auto increment field?

Comment: @Testy What do you want to manage? It is generated automatically as the words "auto increment" indicate. You might want `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`
`

Comment: @Testy if there is something unclear with handling IDs, just open a new question as this is another issue.

Comment: @Tasty  if you have a composite unique index on two columns, you can have same roomid multiple times in the table so long as roomid and date pair is unique